# Which communication protocol should I use? HTTP/TCP

Tags: http, tcp, https, server

I need to develop a system, One server (with static IP, running c# application web/win) and multiple clients (running winforms c# application).

Client send data and related images on a specified time as scheduled job in windows. Maximum of 20000 entries uploaded a day from each client.

Currently 5 clients I have, in future it will increase up to 30-50

My question is I need to develop server system (Windows based), Which listens to client Data Uploads and stores in server, restores it to client when requested. I'm googling about this problem and found TCP is much faster than HTTP/HTTPS.

I need a final solution, that which protocol and implementation method I should use. what are the advantages of that protocol over the other.

### Notes:

1. Preferred environment : MS Server 2008 or higher, with static IP/Private server.
2. Database MSSQL Server 2008+ / MySQL / Postgres.
3. Client application are windows based and using POSTGRES DataBase.
4. Server application must be secure.
5. Data can be send as JSON,XML,PlainText.